# Userform display due date based on date entered by user

Tags: excel, datetime, vba

I am relatively new to VBA (self-taught based on a lot a of google and some tutorials).

I am creating a userform, wherein the user enters the date an application was received (default value set on current date), 
and I have a second textbox below where I would like for it to display the due date for response (add 30 days)

I am not sure how to add the 30 days so that it displays the due date live on the user form, is it possible?

[Userform picture of the two textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIyMH.jpg)

I tried using something along the lines of

`responseduetext.Value = Format(DateAdd("d", 30, datereceivedtext.Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")`

This works, but the value doesn't update if I change the received date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned any code or logic how you want to trigger the calculation, so I need to guess here, but the idea behind it is simple. You need to trigger this:

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text + DAY(30)
```

Now you probably want to detect whether it's a valid date in the first textbox, you could do that with:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
   If IsDate(TextBox1.Text) Then
      TextBox2.Text = CDate(TextBox1.Text) + Day(30)
   Else
      TextBox2.Text = ""
   End If
End Sub
```

So everytime TextBox1 changes Excel evaluates the input and if possible adds 30 days. You'll probably see that it also evaluates e.g. "01/02", if you want to block this, you could add more to the if clause above (e.g. `If IsDate(TextBox1.Text) And Len(TextBox1.Text)>9 Then` )

Comment: I got it work, thanks for your help.!! 

`Private Sub datereceivedtext_Change()


'make sure the entered item is a date, and generate a due date


If IsDate(datereceivedtext.Value) Then

responseduetext.Value = Format(DateAdd("d", 30, datereceivedtext.Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")
End If`

Comment: @kitkat1224 no problem - if it solved your question, please accept the solution so people see the question is solved. If you have a different solution, add another answer...